# How to mock a url path returning response in Django / Python?

Tags: python, django

I have a function like this:

```
def get_some_data(api_url, **kwargs)
        # some logic on generating headers
        # some more logic
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers, params)
        return response
```

I need to create a fake/mock "api_url", which, when made request to, would generate a valid response.
I understand how to mock the response:

```
def mock_response(data):
        response = requests.Response()
        response.status_code = 200
        response._content = json.dumps(data)
        return response
```

But i need to make the test call like this:

```
def test_get_some_data(api_url: some_magic_url_path_that_will_return_mock_response):
```

Any ideas on how to create an url path returning a response within the scope of the test (only standard Django, Python, pytest, unittest) would be very much appreciated

Comment: First result on Google search: https://realpython.com/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/

Comment: That was really fast, i have read that also before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very well written and more than clear on how to mock whatever you want. But, let say you have a service that makes the 3rd party API call:

```
def foo(url, params):
  # some logic on generating headers
  # some more logic
  response = requests.get(url, headers, params)
  return response
```

In your test you want to mock the return value of this service.

```
@patch("path_to_service.foo")
def test_api_call_response(self, mock_response):
  mock_response.return_value = # Whatever the return value you want it to be

  # Here you call the service as usual 
  response = foo(..., ...)
  
  # Assert your response
```